# admin panel not log in magento?

Tags: login, redirect, admin-panel

When I enter a wrong email/password, it says:

> Invalid User Name or Password.

error.

But correct email, password does not show any error and also does not redirect to dashboard.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

- Go to: [Magento Root Folder]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
- Override it using your own package name.
- Comment out below lines-

`'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
 'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()`

and remember to remove comma(,) from the line above these three.

Note: Remember that above file is in core Magento folder, so override it using your own package name.

Please delete **`var/cache`** folder and reload page.

Comment: I deleted the comment. But the advice to change core code still is still not helpful. If you at least explain briefly what "override it using your own package name" means, you'll get my upvote.

Comment: Added point to override. Thanks for reminding. :)